# How do I schedule a Skype Broadcast Meeting programmatically?

Tags: live-streaming, skype-for-business, ucwa

I need to schedule meetings through [Skype Broadcast](https://broadcast.skype.com) as part of an application that I am building. I would like to be able to automatically schedule the meeting for the user, based on information that my application has.

I have looked into this through the [existing APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/unifiedcommunicationswebapi2_0) in Skype for Business Online, but haven't found anything for Skype Broadcast meetings. I am hoping that someone has experience with this or can at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi, have you found the way? I have to show the live broadcast meeting, Any suggestion or have any api documentation you found?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the Skype for Business Broadcast team directly and they informed me that this functionality is not yet available from their application. They directed me to their UserVoice site where [a request is already pending](https://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/34012345-make-broadcast-skype-com-api-publicly-available) to add this feature. Hopefully this will be addressed soon.

If this answer helps anyone, consider visiting their UserVoice site and voting on this issue. It would certainly help me!